# Having trouble importing mysql file into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, utf-8, import, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem when I try to import a mysql table from my computer. There is an error code in phpmyadmin #1071

Error

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE user_info(

user_id BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED,
screen_name VARCHAR( 25 ) ,
name VARCHAR( 200 ) ,
followers INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED,
friends INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED,
description VARCHAR( 350 ) ,
image_url VARCHAR( 200 ) ,
last_update DATETIME,
location VARCHAR( 200 ) ,
FOREIGN KEY ( user_id ) REFERENCES users( user_id ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( user_id, screen_name, name, followers, description, image_url, location, friends )
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the misuse of PRIMARY KEY - primary key is something that distunguishes one row from another, so using all the possible columns to make a primary key is wrong.

Something went wrong with export of your database, so probably a little tweaking to the script can resolve the problem. Another option is to try the export of the database again, but with different parameters.

As I see it - you should add an integer id column, just to diferentiate between records, and make it - and only this one column, unless there is some special reason behind it - a primary key.